# Auto CW limit (number of answers)

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

It would seem to me that with code golf, it will be much easier for legit questions to reach the auto conversion to Community Wiki due to the number of answers (multiple languages, multiple attempts in each language).

Should we/can we have this limit increased if this proves to be the case?

Answer (score 20):

Some history: the auto-CW thing was instituted because I used my [Stack overflow code golf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62188) question as a vehicle for rep-whoring (since getting rep via code golf used to be much easier than via "real" questions, back when there wasn't an explicit ban on non-CW golf questions). In fact, the person who asked for that feature specifically linked to my post as a reason. :-P

This is obviously irrelevant for this site, so I'd advocate that auto-CW be removed entirely.

Comment: Way to own up ;) and I agree.

Answer (score 0):

It probably will be an issue, but I think we'll have to observe this over time to see if it's necessary and how far to push it up. I'm fairly sure it can be done.