# Remove Auto CW Limit

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, community-wiki

The auto CW limit of 60 answers should be removed. The good questions that have been around a while, such as [Golf you a quine for great good!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69/golf-you-a-quine-for-great-good) get a lot of different answers; good for code-golf. It doesn't make since to auto CW all the answers and it when 60 answers are reached.

There have been other requests, such as [Please raise or remove CW limits on Code Golf SE site](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238/please-raise-or-remove-cw-limits-on-code-golf-se-site/239#239) (status-completed, but this answer asks for complete removal), and [Auto CW limit (number of answers)](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29/auto-cw-limit-number-of-answers/33#33). I fully agree with these requests, but since they were posted so long ago, I thought I'd renew the request.

Comment: Note that in [this thread](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/238/please-raise-or-remove-cw-limits-on-code-golf-se-site/239#239) the answer suggesting complete removal is *not* from a site admin. Instead, the [answer provided by site admins](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242/9387), which came along with the [tag:status-completed] tag, spelled out exactly what was changed - the CW limits were dramatically increased, in comparison to the standard used for other sites. That said, they did leave open the option for later review if this wasn't sufficient.

Comment: @Iszi I noticed. I feel that the limit is not enough. I think that it should be removed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update:** [this is now removed *network-wide*.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/putting-the-community-back-in-wiki/) There is a flag that'll be raised in extreme circumstances though, so at least mods will be aware of runaway answers.

Comment: I don't think that we should put a historical lock on the hottest network question.

Comment: As I already said in chat: The answers in the [Trolling homework questions - sorting](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/16226/trolling-homework-questions-sorting) have a better quality than the average "language, score - code" answers, and people should be able to get reputation from that.

Comment: Changing the rules that apply to ALL questions for the sake of ONE question usually isn't a great idea. There are 10 other questions with >= 60 answers: how do those look?

Comment: In which other questions here in codegolf the auto-CW was a good thing? I looked to the other 10 questions whit >= 60 answers, and none of them should be CW IMHO. So I think that this is changing the rules that apply to ALL questions for the sake of ALL questions. BTW, it has 94 answers and 20,000+ views now and it still did not completed 24 hours since I posted it, so it is expected to still grow much more.

Comment: Yes yes yes, set to 9000 or something. Auto-CW is *meaningless* here since the questions naturally garner lots of answers by their nature of being contests. This could happen again in the future.

Answer (score 5):

Just so people can tell what happened.

[The auto-cw limit has now been set to 500 answers](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238/please-raise-or-remove-cw-limits-on-code-golf-se-site/242#comment2859_242). I personally think that if any question reaches that amount of answers, then something is wrong, so I applaud this limit.

Comment: [Something must be wrong](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/55422/66833)