# Un-community wiki questions

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

As established in [Remove Auto CW Limit](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/763/9498) , the auto-community wiki limit is not 500 answers. However, there are many questions left on the site that are marked community wiki because they have >60 answers.

We should remove the community wiki from those posts. There is now no reason for them to be marked community wiki.

Questions that are community wiki but shouldn't be (feel free to add to this list):

- [99 Bottles Of Beer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2/9498)
- [Code Golf Christmas Edition: How to print out a Christmas tree of height N](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/4244/9498)
- [Obfuscated Hello World](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/307/9498)
- [What's my name? Produce the name of the language indirectly](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1091/9498)

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1294/anagram-code-golf is another one, but I can't add it to the list because you can't edit posts on Meta.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I agree they should be converted into normal posts. However, a staff member would have to do so, because when I last looked into this, I had to unwiki each answer, in addition to the question. I don't look forward to doing this for 60+ answers. :-)

Comment: This. It is painful for mods to handle such large number of posts.

Comment: I've just got word that even staff don't have an action that allows them to unwiki all the answers in one go, and that the best we can do is use a script (which has to be rate-limited, yes). Hah. :-D

Comment: Ouch. I feel your pain.

Comment: So turn making the script into a code-golf question. ;)

Comment: @TimSeguine Has this been done? I would like to make such challenge...